# Error in SQL syntax, but the query work well on Access MS

Tags: mysql, sql, select

On Access MS this query work well

```
select Name, LastName, Email, [Name] + [LastName] + [Email] as ThePass from student;
```

But it doesn't work on MySQL, saying 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'.

The idea is to **auto-fill** a field on the same table based on values of other fields.

Comment: write the full error message

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Name] + [LastName] + [Email] AS ThePass FROM student LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: MS Access and MySQL are not the same, why would you expect a query on one to work on the other?

Comment: Use concat() to concat Name + LastName + Email

Comment: Also, please tell me you're not concating a few things together as a password (as the SQL you're doing implies)

Comment: Why do you have [Name] + [LastName] + [Email] ? I'm pretty sure this is where it is failing in MySQL. If your only looking to select the three fields then do this : `select Name, LastName, Email as ThePass from student;`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Come on @a_horse_with_no_name , i'm not noob, i know the basic syntax of SQL, i was lied from Access.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen thinking that both technologies use the same syntax

Comment: The "basic syntax of SQL" does **not** allow square brackets for identifiers. The "basic syntax of SQL" also does **not** allow `+` for string concatenation. MS-Access might allow that but standard SQL (= "basic SQL") does not allow that.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you want is:

```
select Name, LastName, Email,
       concat(Name,  LastName, Email) as ThePass
from student;
```

The string concatenation function in MySQL is `concat()`, not `+`.  And square braces are not recognized by MySQL.  You should learn the basic of MySQL if you are going to use it.

Comment: The string concatenation in MySQL _could_ also be `||` if it is run in ANSI mode

Comment: I'm trying sir. Thanks :P

Comment: To make your SQL journey even more interesting, each DB engine has its quirks. In Oracle, you'd use: Name || LastName || Email as ThePass

Comment: @ptrk: `||` is what has been defined by the SQL standard back in '86 for string concatenation. It is not something specific to Oracle. Many, many DBMS use that (Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Firebird, Informix, H2, HSQLDB, and many more)

Comment: As a note, ANSI has also blessed the `concat()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, columns are denoted either as bare words or with forward quotes.
Additionally, the `+` operator cannot be used to concat strings - instead, you can have no operator (the concatination is implicit), or explicitly call the `concat` function:

```
select `Name`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Name` `LastName` `Email` as ThePass from student;
```

Or:

```
select `Name`, `LastName`, `Email`, CONCAT(`Name`, `LastName`, `Email`) as ThePass from student;
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the implicit concatenation

Comment: Is there a test case that demonstrates the  "implicit concatenation" behavior? Is there some setting of SQL_MODE that has to be disabled or enabled to get this to work? (I've observed this behavior with string literals before, but never with column identifiers.)